# Resttemplate: Get an List of Object by passing one Object to the RestAPI

Tags: java, spring, rest

Hi I searched everywhere for an answer but I can't find one. I need to get a list of Object. Before I have to pass these object to a Rest API where the code will generate this list of objects.

This is my method:

```
public static List<Cashflow> generateCashflow(Credit credit) {      
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://localhost:9080/example/";
    ...
 }
```

This was my last try:

```
    ResponseEntity<? extends ArrayList<Cashflow>> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, darlehen, (Class<? extends ArrayList<Cashflow>>)ArrayList.class);
      ArrayList<Cashflow> cashflowList = responseEntity.getBody();
      System.out.println(cashflowList.get(0).getCashflow());        
      return cashflowList;
}
```

This is my Rest API controller:

```
@RestController
public class CashflowGenerator {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/example", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Cashflow> genCashflow(@RequestBody Credit credit) {
        List<Cashflow> cashflowList = new ArrayList<Cashflow>();        
        // Some Math Stuff
        cashflowList.add(cashflow); 
        return cashflowList;
    }
```

Here is my `Cashflown` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Cashflow {

    private Date date;
    private double cashflow;

    public Cashflow() {
        super();
    }
```

On running this as a maven build on a IBM web sphere server, I got this message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast
>   to de.example.Cashflow

Comment: *//I tried some things*: what did you try? What happened?

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post code in comments.

Comment: I closed as duplicate. The duplicate explains how to do. In general, code to interfaces (List<Cashflow>) rather than implementations (ArrayList<Cashflow>).

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day!!! It worked :D